# WordPress Query: ORDER BY CASE WHEN

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, case

I want to first display the posts that match a particular `meta_key => cr_id` and order those by another `'meta_key' => 'cr_list_price'` and then display the rests of the posts that are also ordered by `'meta_key' => 'cr_list_price'`.

This is my current code which does everything I want except show the posts where `cr_id = 4`.

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'properties',
        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'cr_list_price',
                'value' => array($minPrice, $maxPrice),
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'cr_prop_bed',
                'value' => $beds,
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
        ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'cr_list_price'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If I was using raw `MySQL` I'd do something like `ORDER BY CASE WHEN` in my query, however I'm not sure how or if I can accomplish this with WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you could add a filter to the query by adding that little extension on there. I'm thinking maybe [posts_orderby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby)

**Function**

```
function filter_case($orderby = '') {
  $orderby .= 'CASE WHEN [some conditions]';
  return $orderby;
}
```

**Before Query**

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_case' );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_case' );
```

I cant gaurantee this will work first time but it could be worked on if you think it's worth pursuing? List of WP_Query filters are [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#WP_Query_Filters).

Comment: i had the [same issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177650/sort-search-with-posts-orderby/177653#177653) and this answer helped me figure it out