# SQL query with CASE WHEN used in WP_query wordpress function

Tags: sql, wordpress, case

I have this SQL query: `` SELECT * FROM `wpgo_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'price' ORDER BY CASE WHEN meta_value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, meta ``*`value+0 DESC;` *that works for me but I need to convert it so it's used by the wordpress apply_filters function.

I have tried multiple things including this [WordPress Query: ORDER BY CASE WHEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084199/wordpress-query-order-by-case-when)
But then it returns an empty list. I know the query works because I have tested it manually.

I also tried this and it looks like it should work, but I get an empty list as well.

```
$query_args['meta_key'] = 'fave_property_price';
$query_args['orderby'] = "CASE WHEN meta_value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, metavalue+0 DESC;";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want your numeric `meta_value` results to appear after the non-numeric ones.

In SQL you can simplify your ORDER BY like this.

```
ORDER BY (meta_value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'), meta_value DESC
```

It works because the output of Boolean comparison operations appear a 1 for true and 0 for false.The parentheses aren't strictly necessary but they make the code a bit easier to read.

But, you cannot just stuff this SQL style clause into a [WP_Query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) object. Replacing the ORDER BY clause is tricky.

Start by converting this into a WP_Query operation. Those things don't look a whole lot like pure SQL. You need something like this, not debugged.

```php
$q = new WP_Query ( 
   ['meta_key' => 'price',
    'order'    => 'DESC',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
   ]);
```

Then you'll get your posts in numeric order by price, with oddball results for non-numeric prices. Run this query and convince yourself you get the posts you want, even if not in the perfect order.

Only then, put a filter handler on the [posts_orderby](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) filter to put in your SQLish custom ordering clause. The post you referenced shows how to do that: [WordPress Query: ORDER BY CASE WHEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084199/wordpress-query-order-by-case-when)

Use John Blackbourn's Query Monitor plugin to see what your query looks like in real life, after all the WP_Query code finishes assembling it. The correct use of query filters can sometimes be confusing.

If code is poetry then the WP_Query code is an occult spell invocation chant. Sigh.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It makes more sense but however, it's still not working for me. The add_filter doesn't add the ORDER BY SQL. It works perfectly in PHP my admin when I run the SQL directly though.

Comment: Just so you know, I have never, even once, gotten this to work right without stepping through the WP_Query() code with a debugger from my filter. It's ***##$#()$ hard to get right.